# MVC 4 Paging with JavaScript

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, datatable

I'm wondering what the easiest way to do this would be. Here is my scenario: I have an application that displays an audit history for a user. Currently, this is set to return only 100 records, and display only 20 of them. Is there a simple way to use js to implement paging that would display all 100 entries, and then when the "Next Page" button is clicked it will fetch the next 100 entries? Here is what the code looks like:

In the UserHelper I have:

```
public AuditInfo GetAuditInfo(SearchInfo searchInfo)
    {
        AuditInfo auditInfo = new AuditInfo();
        if (searchInfo != null)
        {
            List<AuditRecord> auditRecords =
                UserManager.GetAuditRecords(record => record.Username == searchInfo.UserName,
                                                records => records.OrderByDescending(record => record.Date), 0, 100);
            auditInfo.AuditRecords = auditRecords;
        }
        return auditInfo;
    }
```

And in the controller I have:

```
public ActionResult AuditHistory(String username)
    {
        SearchInfo searchInfo = new SearchInfo { UserName = username };

        AuditInfo auditInfo = _userHelper.GetAuditInfo(searchInfo);
        Response.CacheControl = "no-cache";
        Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
        Response.Expires = -1;

        return PartialView(auditInfo);
    }
```

The view model simply returns a List AuditRecords, and iterates through them in the view, with some javascript for a datatable as so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#tbl_std_documents').dataTable({
        "bFilter": false,
        "bPaginate": false,
        "bSort": false,
        "bInfo": false
    });

    $("a.comment").fancybox({
        'type': 'inline',
        'transitionIn': 'elastic',
        'transitionOut': 'elastic',
        'hideOnContentClick': true,
        'speedIn': 600,
        'speedOut': 200,
        'overlayShow': false
    });

});
</script>
```

Turning on the bPaginate and bFilter allows me to page through the 100 returned records 10 at a time, and allows filtering based on a search box. What I would like is to be able to view 100 entries at a time, and have a function to grab the next 100 from the database. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an AJAX call to grab additional records from database and return those as a JSON object.

This is an example of a JSON method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetRows(int page, int rowsPerPage) 
{
    var data = //grab data from database
    return Json(data);
}
```

And this is javascript call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("GetRows")',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { 'page': 2, 'rowsPerPage': 100  },
    success: SuccessHandler,
    error: OnFailHandler
});

function SuccessHandler(data) 
{     
    //data has the same properties like the object you returned in JSON method on server
    //you probably want to update your datatable here with new data
}
```

Hope it helps. Good luck!

Comment: Where would I put the ajax call? inside the javascript I already have on the page?

Comment: Yes, and in the SuccessHandler function the passed parameter would be the JSON object returned from server.

Comment: I'm not very good with javascript, how would the SuccessHandler look/work?

Comment: I've added a sample function, hope you have a better idea how it works now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MVCPager for this. http://mvcpager.codeplex.com/

The good thing about this is that it uses a PagedList type. Check it out, it will give you what you need.